# I need help on my css button code

Tags: html, css, button, user-interface

I want to know, what can write on my css code to get this buttons...

I've tried some border(and radius) stuuf, but I didn't get what I wanted!

https://i.stack.imgur.com/3yPuL.png

Comment: Show us what you've tried!

Comment: What is *it* that "*you wanted*"? What did you not get when you tried the "*border (and radius) [stuff]*"? What, *precisely*, did you try, and what went wrong?

Comment: As you can see, there are a lot of people that are willing to help you . I just wrote the CSS code in under a minute. But we like to see what sort of efforts you are making, rather than just give you free code.

Comment: http://www.tc3.edu/instruct/sbrown/pic/miracle.jpg

Comment: I'm assuming you want the buttons to have a rounded border?  If so, just do `border-radius` to your css rule.

Answer (score 0):

Think that this is what you want. Your html:

```
<input type="button" class="b" value="button">
```

Your css:

```
.b{
    border:solid;
    border-width:2px;
    border-radius:5px;
    background-color:white;
    font-size:20px;
    color:grey;
    padding:6px;
}

.b:hover{
    border-color:#aaaaaa;
    color:#aaaaaa;
}
.b:active{
    border-color:#555555;
    color:#555555;
}
```

Love it? ;-)

[**JSFIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/UstsP/1/)

Answer (score 0):

Here's an almost exact duplicate.  You can study this code for your own buttons: http://jsfiddle.net/M3uE9/1/.

HTML:

```
<button>Portfolio</button>
```

CSS:

```
button {
    border: 2px solid rgba(100, 100, 100, 1);
    border-radius: 5px;
    padding: 10px;
    background-color: #fff;
    color: rgba(50, 50, 50, 1);
    text-transform: uppercase;
    letter-spacing: 1px;
    font: 14px/1 Sans-Serif;
}
```